# Android - ACTION_POINTER_UP not called until movement of remaining touch

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, multi-touch

Whilst trying to debug a multi-touch issue, I ended up stripping my onTouchEvent code right down to see what was going on, and found the following issue. Am I missing something? Cheers in advance!

- Finger 1 down: ACTION_DOWN is called – OK.
- Finger 2 down: ACTION_POINTER_DOWN is called – OK

Now this is the problem:

- Finger 1 (the 1st finger) up: ACTION_POINTER_UP is not called. But it IS called when Finger 2 is moved.

By holding Finger 2 as steady as possible when Finger 1 is released, it’s very noticeable that the above is happening.

Here’s my simple test code, the vars are just continuously printed out:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getActionMasked())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            jpACTIONDOWN++;
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            jpACTIONPOINTERDOWN++;
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            jpACTIONUP++;
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            jpACTIONPOINTERUP++;
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            jpACTIONMOVE++;
            return true;
        default:
            jpDEFAULT++;
    }
    return false;
}
```